# Is there any evidence Mat Cauthon was inspired by Matthias Corvinus?

Tags: character-analysis, inspiration, historical-context, robert-jordan, wheel-of-time

[Matthias Corvinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthias_Corvinus), also known as the Raven King, was King of Hungary and Croatia for a while in the 1400s. He was a noted general, and extensively made use of Hussite mercenaries in his battles. He was also (reportedly) popular with commoners and married into his title.

[Matrim Cauthon](https://library.tarvalon.net/index.php?title=Matrim_Cauthon), also known as the Prince of the Ravens and Knotai in his later life, was the Rodholder of the Seanchan army and consort of the current empress. In addition, he was the leader of the Band of the Red Hand, a group of soldiers that refuse the title of mercenaries.

These names seem pretty similar to me, especially considering the use of ravens in both of them. Is there any evidence that Jordan based Mat's character (in part) off of Matthias Corvinus? This occurred to me while playing Civilization 6 earlier today. So far I've only found [this (incredibly comprehensive) blog post](http://13depository.blogspot.com/2002/03/character-parallels-mat.html) on the subject.

There seems to be a definite parallel here, is there any evidence that Mat was based off Matt?